# Any two open balls in $\Bbb R^n$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Any two open balls in $\Bbb R^n$ are homeomorphic.

I am finding difficulty to construct a continuous bijective function which can map an open ball to an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$. Will it be easier if we shift the ball to the origin??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just show that they’re all homeomorphic to the open unit ball at the origin. If $B(p,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $p$, the map

$$h:B(0,1)\to B(p,r):x\mapsto rx+p$$

is a homeomorphism.

Comment: is this map also a diffeomorphism? In that case, can we assume that for any smooth manifold $M$, with a chart $(U,\varphi : U \to \widehat{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^n)$, we have that $\widehat{U} = B(0,1)$, since we can always compose with the diffeomorphism $h$ to create a new chart?

Comment: @Sigurd: I’ve no idea, I’m afraid: differential topology is outside my range.